# Why I can't access Object methods from Object instance?

Tags: javascript

There are many methods for Object constructor, like Object.assign() and  Object.create(), but why I can't access these methods from Object instances?

```
var test  = new Object();
//this will return error
test.create();
```

Comment: simply because `Object.create` isn't `Object.prototype.create` ... `test.create` would imply `Object.prototype.create` is a method ... but it isn't

Answer (score 1):

That is because `create`, `assign` and many others are static methods. Static methods belongs to the class so you cannot call them from an instance of that class. [Here you can find more info about static methods in js](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes/static)

```
class Tripple {
  static tripple(n) {
    n = n | 1;
    return n * 3;
  }
}

class BiggerTripple extends Tripple {
  static tripple(n) {
    return super.tripple(n) * super.tripple(n);
  }
}

console.log(Tripple.tripple());
console.log(Tripple.tripple(6));
console.log(BiggerTripple.tripple(3));
var tp = new Tripple();
console.log(tp.tripple()); //Logs 'tp.tripple is not a function'
```

Answer (score 0):

You already created a object with new variable. You can try this to create new object using create keyword

```
var testObj = Object.create(null);

typeof(testObj) // Object
console.log(testObj) // Object with prototype object as null

// Set property to object
testObj.name = "Stackoverflow";

console.log(testObj)
```